# fetch URL parameter using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

I want to fetch url parameter in my class. my application based on Spring MVC.

While calling url: `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/dir/register.do?id=26` it gives error 400

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public ModelAndView finalPage(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
   // code...
}
```

Anybody can solve my problem.

Comment: How do you think `@PathVariable` works and why?

Comment: Use `@QueryParam` instead of `@PathVariable`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not sure, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> I want to fetch url parameter in my class

but you are using [`@PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) which

> indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a **URI template variable**

You don't have a uri template variable called `id` in your mapping.

What you really need is a [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) explains how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, I used "@RequestParam" and its work perfect. but what if i did not pass id in url? in some cases i am not passing parameter with url

Comment: @Bharat If you look at the javadoc I linked, you can set `required` to `false`.